# Upload images in app RN Strapi backend - blob make problem

Tags: react-native, blob, strapi

I’m trying to do a simple photo attachment in a React Native app. Basically, my strapi backend is set up correctly to work with cloudinary , because with Postman I manage to send a request and attach an image. There is some problem with the blob but I can’t find a solution. I also tried with axios and what not, but the error it gives me is “TypeError: Network request failed]”

`   import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button,  Image, StyleSheet, Text, useWindowDimensions, View, } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

```
import { useAuth } from '../../../hooks';


export default function UploadScreen() {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const { user, updateUser } = useAuth();
  
console.log(user);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
      base64: true,
    });

    //console.log(result);

    if (!result.canceled) {
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);

        const base64 = `data:image/png;base64,${result.assets[0].base64}`;
        const blob = await fetch(base64).then((res) => res.blob());

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('files', blob, 'avatar.png');
        formData.append('ref', 'user'); // Model name
        formData.append('refId', user.id); // User ID
        formData.append('field', 'avatar_url'); // Field name in the model

        const response = await fetch('http://10.6.7.55:1337/api/upload', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
        });
console.log(response);
        if (response.ok) {
          const responseData = await response.json();
          const updatedUser = { ...user, avatar_url: responseData[0]?.url };

          // Update user data in your app state
          updateUser(updatedUser);
        } else {
          console.error('Failed to upload image to Strapi');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during image upload:', error);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Pick an image from camera roll" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && <Image source={{uri: user.avatar_url}}
        style={{width:'100%',height:110,borderTopLeftRadius:10,
      borderTopRightRadius:10}} />}

      <View>
        {user && <Image source={{ uri: user?.avatar_url }} style={styles.avatar} />}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})`

I tried using Buffer, I also tried with axios but the result is the same.

Comment: Have you tried adding "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" to the header of the fetch request?

Comment: I tried I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with react-native-document-picker

```
import DocumentPicker, {isCancel, types} from "react-native-document-picker";

// picker function
export const pickSingleDocument = async setDocument => {
  try {
    const pickerResult = await DocumentPicker.pickSingle({
      presentationStyle: "fullScreen",
      copyTo: "cachesDirectory",
      type: [types.images],
    });
    setDocument({
      name: pickerResult.name,
      type: pickerResult.type,
      uri: pickerResult.uri,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (isCancel(error)) {
      toastNotification("cancelled");
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  }
};
```

```
// upload
  const createRowWithoutFile = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const payload = {
        data: {
          doc_folder: {
            connect: [folderId],
          },
        },
      };
      const response = await Api.post("/docs", payload);
      if (response.status == 200) {
        const formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("field", "file");
        formdata.append("ref", "api::doc.doc");
        formdata.append("refId", response?.data?.data?.id); // 18 here
        formdata.append("files", document);
        const response = await Api.postForm("/upload", payload);
      }
    } catch (error) {}
  };
```

PS. need to create a file row and add that in the reference, this is the catch, behind the scenario its uploads the asset in the bucket and links it up with the table row

[image]